# how to force an image background to fit smaller div center

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div id="img-frame">
<img src="mypathimg.png"/>
</div>
```

use `img` 100% will work but it unlike Facebook, it shrink but show the centre of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<div id="img-frame">
    <div style="background:url(mypathimg.png) 100% 100%;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the other answers are complete, change the markup to:

```
<div id="img-frame">
    <div style="background-image:url(yoururl.png)" class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Now add CSS:

```
.img-frame > .img {
  background-size:cover;       /* Scale to fit optimistically */
  background-position:center;  /* Scale from center */
  width:100%;                  /* Same width as parent */
  height:100%;                 /* Same height as parent */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<div id="img-frame">
    <div style="background-size: cover;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the width and height of the image to 100% if you don't want it as a background image. You might need to provide an example of what you have so far and be more specific though.

```
#img-frame{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#img-frame img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use css3 rule: background-size as

```
<div id="img-frame">
<div style='background:url(mypathimg.png) ;background-size:contain;' ></div>
```